# Prolog syntax error operator expected

Tags: prolog

It says there's an error operator expected. I know this syntax error is in line 5 but I can't figure it out.  I have highlighted that line with ** thx.

```
 action(X : Y,0 : Y):-X>0.
action(X : Y,X : 0):-Y>0.
action(X : Y,4:Y):-X<4. 
 action(X : Y,X : 3):-Y<3.
 **action(X : Y,4 : Z):- X<4, Z is Y−(4−X), Z>=0.**

 Path(X):- 
   path(0 : 0,[0 : 0],X).
```

Answer (score 2):

Prolog predicate names must begin with a lower case letter. So as @CapelliC points out, `Path(X) :0-...` is going to be a problem.

But your syntax error on line 5 is because you copy/pasted this code from something online or from an eBook perhaps. In your expression, `Y−(4−X)` those `−` symbols are not minuses but something else that look like minuses (perhaps EM dashes). Try retyping line 5 manually, and the problem will go away.

This one is a problem:

```
Y−(4−X)
```

And this one is correct:

```
Y-(4-X)
```

There is actually a subtle difference in length of the dash you can see if you look closely. The second example is an actual dash or minus (ASCII code hex `2d`). The first example of a dash is a special character (a hex dump shows a character code of `59 88 92`). This is an issue with copy/pasting code from an eBook or other electronic document, since there are several characters used for visual convenience that aren't the specific one required by the language.

Answer (score 1):

the error is the clause following

```
Path(X):-
 ...
```

should be

```
path(X):- 
 ...
```